# 長期でstaticな値を使い回したい

Tags: php

**やりたいこと**
・MySQLから取得したデータを、cronを使用して一日一回、順番に1件づつ投稿したい
・例えば期間半年をかけて

**疑問**
・配列形式で取得した場合、前回投稿した順番をどうやって把握すれば良いでしょうか？

**案1**
・その時点の番号をファイル出力して、翌日読込

**案2**
・「最初に投稿した日」と「実際に投稿する日」の差分で計算
・「最初に投稿した日」は結局どこかに保存しなければいけない？ もしくは「マジックナンバー」として指定？

**質問**
・こういった場合、普通はどうやるのでしょうか？

Comment: 投稿というのがよく分からないのですが、何か記事の下書きがあって、それを順次公開していく感じでしょうか？cronのログを出力しているのなら"投稿"した記事のIDか何かを出力させておいてログ末尾を参照するか、DBにキュー処理用のテーブルを作成する、記事に公開日などの情報を持たせる、などが思いつきますね。やりたいことを察するに、どれにしても2重処理された場合でも1日に必ず1件になるようにした方がいいとは思いますが……。

Comment: 「cronのログを出力しているのなら」。なるほど対象データによって対応方法も変わってくるわけですね。今回は、別の用途としてDBへ格納しているメモを、1日1回Twitterへも順番に投稿したいと思い質問しました。コメントを読んで、「DBにキュー処理用のテーブルを作成する」方法が良いかなと思いました

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHPでstaticを共有することは、基本的にできないですね。

質問の認識が間違っているかもしれないので、確認の為、少し値を変えて解釈を記載します。
■一週間分（７レコード）のデータを、特定の順番で１日ごとに処理していきたい
※日数　：1⇒2⇒3⇒4⇒5⇒6⇒7⇒8⇒9⇒....
※データ：A⇒B⇒C⇒D⇒E⇒F⇒G⇒A⇒B⇒....

上記の場合、
■方法１（単純）※この方式の場合、途中でデータが増えると駄目（増えたデータを手メンテすればOK）
１．初期状態（全未処理）の「優先順位」のカラムを用意する
２．「投稿した日時」を保持するカラムを用意する
３．その日のレコードを取得する際に、「投稿した日時」の昇順、優先順位の昇順の１レコード目がその日に投稿するデータになる
※MYSQLは昇順の場合NULLが先頭になる、１日ごとの場合、投稿日が一番古いデータが自動的にその日の投稿データになる

```
・１日目（2016/10/01）
SELECT * FROM 投稿情報テーブル ORDER BY 投稿日, 優先順位 LMIT 1;
+----------+------------+--------------+
| 優先順位 | 投稿データ | 投稿した日時 |
+----------+------------+--------------+
|        1 |          A |         NULL | ←　投稿日がNULLなので「優先順位」の昇順の１件目が投稿データ（投稿処理ごに投稿日に日付を設定する）
+----------+------------+--------------+
|        2 |          B |         NULL |
+----------+------------+--------------+
|        3 |          C |         NULL |
+----------+------------+--------------+
|        4 |          D |         NULL |
+----------+------------+--------------+
|        5 |          E |         NULL |
+----------+------------+--------------+
|        6 |          F |         NULL |
+----------+------------+--------------+
|        7 |          G |         NULL |
+----------+------------+--------------+

・２日目（2016/10/02）
SELECT * FROM 投稿情報テーブル ORDER BY 投稿日, 優先順位 LMIT 1;
+----------+------------+--------------+
| 優先順位 | 投稿データ | 投稿した日時 |
+----------+------------+--------------+
|        2 |          B |         NULL |←　MYSQLは昇順の場合NULLが先頭になる為、「投稿日」が設定されていないデータの「優先順位」の昇順の１件目が投稿データ（投稿処理ごに投稿日に日付を設定する）
+----------+------------+--------------+
|        3 |          C |         NULL |
+----------+------------+--------------+
|        4 |          D |         NULL |
+----------+------------+--------------+
|        5 |          E |         NULL |
+----------+------------+--------------+
|        6 |          F |         NULL |
+----------+------------+--------------+
|        7 |          G |         NULL |
+----------+------------+--------------+
|        1 |          A |   2016/10/01 | ←　MYSQLは昇順の場合NULLが先頭になる為、日付が設定されたデータは最後になる
+----------+------------+--------------+

※１日ごとに上記処理を繰り返す
・・・
８日目（2016/10/08）
SELECT * FROM 投稿情報テーブル ORDER BY 投稿日, 優先順位 LMIT 1;
+----------+------------+--------------+
| 優先順位 | 投稿データ | 投稿した日時 |
+----------+------------+--------------+
|        1 |          A |   2016/10/01 | ←　「投稿日」が全て設定されている為、「投稿日」の昇順の１件目が投稿データ
+----------+------------+--------------+
|        2 |          B |   2016/10/02 |
+----------+------------+--------------+
|        3 |          C |   2016/10/03 |
+----------+------------+--------------+
|        4 |          D |   2016/10/04 |
+----------+------------+--------------+
|        5 |          E |   2016/10/05 |
+----------+------------+--------------+
|        6 |          F |   2016/10/06 |
+----------+------------+--------------+
|        7 |          G |   2016/10/07 |
+----------+------------+--------------+

９日目（2016/10/09）
SELECT * FROM 投稿情報テーブル ORDER BY 投稿日, 優先順位 LMIT 1;
+----------+------------+--------------+
| 優先順位 | 投稿データ | 投稿した日時 |
+----------+------------+--------------+
|        2 |          B |   2016/10/02 | ←　「投稿日」が全て設定されている為、「投稿日」の昇順の１件目が投稿データ
+----------+------------+--------------+
|        3 |          C |   2016/10/03 |
+----------+------------+--------------+
|        4 |          D |   2016/10/04 |
+----------+------------+--------------+
|        5 |          E |   2016/10/05 |
+----------+------------+--------------+
|        6 |          F |   2016/10/06 |
+----------+------------+--------------+
|        7 |          G |   2016/10/07 |
+----------+------------+--------------+
|        1 |          A |   2016/10/08 | ←　「投稿日」に投稿した日付を設定する為、日付が設定されたデータは最後になる
+----------+------------+--------------+
```

■方法２（初期化方式）
１．初期状態（全未処理）の「優先順位」のカラムを用意する
２．最後に「投稿する日付」を保持するカラムを用意する
３．当日の投稿データを取得して、データが存在したら投稿、
存在しない場合、優先順位に従って、その日からの投稿日時を各レコードに設定していく
※この日付設定処理のときに未来日のデータがあったらどうするとかを処理する

```
・１日目（2016/10/01）
SELECT * FROM 投稿情報テーブル WHERE 投稿する日時 = 今日の日付;
※初期の段階で投稿する日付を設定しておく
+----------+------------+--------------+
| 優先順位 | 投稿データ | 投稿する日時 |
+----------+------------+--------------+
|        1 |          A |   2016/10/01 | ←　投稿データ
+----------+------------+--------------+
|        2 |          B |   2016/10/02 |
+----------+------------+--------------+
|        3 |          C |   2016/10/03 |
+----------+------------+--------------+
|        4 |          D |   2016/10/04 |
+----------+------------+--------------+
|        5 |          E |   2016/10/05 |
+----------+------------+--------------+
|        6 |          F |   2016/10/06 |
+----------+------------+--------------+
|        7 |          G |   2016/10/07 |
+----------+------------+--------------+


・１日目（2016/10/02）
SELECT * FROM 投稿情報テーブル WHERE 投稿する日時 = 今日の日付;
+----------+------------+--------------+
| 優先順位 | 投稿データ | 投稿する日時 |
+----------+------------+--------------+
|        1 |          A |   2016/10/01 |
+----------+------------+--------------+
|        2 |          B |   2016/10/02 | ←　投稿データ
+----------+------------+--------------+
|        3 |          C |   2016/10/03 |
+----------+------------+--------------+
|        4 |          D |   2016/10/04 |
+----------+------------+--------------+
|        5 |          E |   2016/10/05 |
+----------+------------+--------------+
|        6 |          F |   2016/10/06 |
+----------+------------+--------------+
|        7 |          G |   2016/10/07 |
+----------+------------+--------------+

※１日ごとに上記処理を繰り返す
・・・

・８日目（2016/10/08）
SELECT * FROM 投稿情報テーブル WHERE 投稿する日時 = 今日の日付;
+----------+------------+--------------+
| 優先順位 | 投稿データ | 投稿する日時 |
+----------+------------+--------------+
|        1 |          A |   2016/10/01 |
+----------+------------+--------------+
|        2 |          B |   2016/10/02 | 
+----------+------------+--------------+
|        3 |          C |   2016/10/03 |
+----------+------------+--------------+
|        4 |          D |   2016/10/04 |
+----------+------------+--------------+
|        5 |          E |   2016/10/05 |
+----------+------------+--------------+
|        6 |          F |   2016/10/06 |
+----------+------------+--------------+
|        7 |          G |   2016/10/07 |
+----------+------------+--------------+
                                        ←　投稿データがない

「投稿する日付」を優先順位に従って今日の日付から再設定する
SELECT * FROM 投稿情報テーブル WHERE 投稿する日時 = 今日の日付;
+----------+------------+--------------+
| 優先順位 | 投稿データ | 投稿する日時 |
+----------+------------+--------------+
|        1 |          A |   2016/10/08 | ←　投稿データ
+----------+------------+--------------+
|        2 |          B |   2016/10/09 | 
+----------+------------+--------------+
|        3 |          C |   2016/10/10 |
+----------+------------+--------------+
|        4 |          D |   2016/10/11 |
+----------+------------+--------------+
|        5 |          E |   2016/10/12 |
+----------+------------+--------------+
|        6 |          F |   2016/10/13 |
+----------+------------+--------------+
|        7 |          G |   2016/10/14 |
+----------+------------+--------------+

・９日目（2016/10/09）
SELECT * FROM 投稿情報テーブル WHERE 投稿する日時 = 今日の日付;
+----------+------------+--------------+
| 優先順位 | 投稿データ | 投稿する日時 |
+----------+------------+--------------+
|        1 |          A |   2016/10/08 |
+----------+------------+--------------+
|        2 |          B |   2016/10/09 | ←　投稿データ
+----------+------------+--------------+
|        3 |          C |   2016/10/10 |
+----------+------------+--------------+
|        4 |          D |   2016/10/11 |
+----------+------------+--------------+
|        5 |          E |   2016/10/12 |
+----------+------------+--------------+
|        6 |          F |   2016/10/13 |
+----------+------------+--------------+
|        7 |          G |   2016/10/14 |
+----------+------------+--------------+
```

Comment: 「PHPでstaticを共有することは、基本的にできない」。なるほど、やはりそうなのですね。参考になりました。「方法１（単純）」について、3の処理までは理解できたのですが、翌日以降の処理がよく分かりませんでした。投稿したデータは削除する、という前提でしょうか？　それだと常に先頭に来るので理解できるのですが…。「方法２（初期化方式）」は日付と紐付いている、という意味でしょうか？　「当日の投稿データが存在しない場合」という意味が分かりませんでした。何れにしても、質問した時点では、PHP側で処理することしか念頭になかったのですが、DB側にキュー的なデータを持たせればよいことが分かりました。その方向で検討してみたいと思います。

Comment: 「 ORDER BY 投稿日, 優先順位 LMIT 1」なのですね。なるほどよく分かりました。編集ありがとうございました

Answer (score 0):

投稿後、投稿した日時を更新できるのなら、次の投稿すべきレコードは以下のクエリで取得できます。

```
SELECT *
  FROM 投稿データ
 WHERE 投稿した日時 IS NULL
 ORDER BY 優先順位
 LIMIT 1
```